# Encrypting small packets with low data rate

Tags: encryption, aes, public-key, symmetric, ctr

I'm trying to build my own layer of encryption on top of our bluetooth communication. We can't use bonding because of some specific features we need to support. I'm a beginner when it comes to encryption, and so I wanted to run this by someone with more experience. Please look over my planned approach and point out any flaws or improvements:

1. Communication is between an iPhone and a bluetooth peripheral. At the start of any connection, the iPhone will generate a random public/private key pair. The public key will be sent to the bluetooth device.
2. The bluetooth device will generate a random symmetric key, encrypt it using the iPhone's public key and send it back to the iPhone.
3. All future communication will now be performed using the symmetric key for encryption/decryption.
4. A security passkey that is generated once for the bluetooth device and used to identify an authorized user is encrypted and sent from the iOS device to the bluetooth device. If the passkey is wrong, the connection is killed. If it is correct, the iOS device now has full access to the bluetooth device via encrypted packet communication. Each new connection will have a new private/public key pair and a new symmetric key.

Because packets are maximum 20 bytes and data rate is around 1200 bytes/second, I plan on encrypting packets using AES256 CTR encryption, as this has the advantage of the encrypted data being the same length as the original data.

Are there some flaws to my approach that I'm not aware of? Are there flaws with my plan to use CTR so the encrypted data is the same length as the original? Is there a better approach to accomplish what I want?

#### Edit:

I have a few questions about my specific use case.

1. I only need to keep the security passkey that is transmitted at the beginning of communications secret, as without that, an attacker wouldn't be able to do any sort of replay attack since new security keys are generated each new connection session. Is this flawed thinking?
2. Using Diffie-Hellman to generate a symmetric key, then using a stream cipher (CTR) to encrypt communication, would this be secure? Each packet would be encrypted with a new counter value (initialization vector) that would not be reused for the session, which would also be sent with the encrypted packet for decryption on the other end. My understanding is that this method would be perfectly secure as long as I never used the same initialization vector to encrypt two different packets. Is this correct thinking? My main purpose in wanting to use a stream cipher is so my encrypted data length is the same as the unencrypted data length.
3. Due to point 1 above, is it possible for me to safely get away with using the same initialization vector for all packets encrypted for the entire session, as the next session will have completely different symmetric keys, or will doing this open my protocol up to being decoded by an attacker, enabling them to aquire the passkey mentioned in point 1?

#### Edit2:

Based on comments by Thomas M. DuBuisson, I see that there are several issues with my approach that I hadn't thought of previously. One major issue being I need to make sure I have a solid random number generator on the bluetooth device. In light of the points he made, and after doing more research on how to securely exchange keys with a limited resource device, I thought of another approach that might be easier with the available resources, and I hope a little more secure.
Sorry for my lack of experience in this area, but I'm trying to learn what I can and hopefully not make any stupid mistakes.

Comment: Could you please clarify step 4? How is the passkey verified?

Comment: And is there a particular reason why you can't use DTLS, TLS or [Noise](http://www.noiseprotocol.org/)?

Comment: @SEJPM: For the pairing process, the iOS device will scan a QR code that contains the MAC address of the bluetooth device and a special pairing key. When the pairing key is sent to the bluetooth device, the bluetooth device creates a new passkey, saves it, and sends it back to the iPhone where it is saved. This passkey must be sent at the start of every session. The pairing key is the only way to cause the bluetooth device to generate and send back a new passkey, which would invalidate the old passkey.

Comment: @SEJPM: Like I said, I'm a real beginner when it comes to encryption. I'm not familiar with DTLS or TLS. As far as Noise, it looks like every packet needs to include a 16 byte key. My total packet length is only 20 bytes, and we have our own protocol that we are running within that 20 bytes, so at the most we might be able to spare 4 or 8 bytes for security reasons, although I'd prefer it if there was a method that didn't add any overhead bytes and was still secure.

Comment: Non-ancient versions of the Bluetooth protocol stack include mechanisms for pairing devices and establishing a secure channel. Why aren't you using that instead of rolling your own?

Comment: The problem is, we want the ability to have a single user pair to one of our devices and share the paired device with everyone on their account. If you use the built in methods for bonding and security, you can't share the bonding information with others. Each user that wants to talk to a device would have to do the bonding themselves for each device. We will have a lot of devices in each house, that would be a lot of extra work for each member of a household to bond all the devices. Does that make sense?

Comment: Davido, Quick question on your step 1. How do you plan to enforce authenticity on the initial public key share? What happens if the channel is being monitored during the first step and the attacker sends his public key rather than the key being sent by the iphone?

Comment: You might like to look at a key exchange system I designed and implemented for the embedded world, [link here](https://github.com/GaloisInc/gec).  The target market was UAVs but the notions are much the same.  If you want to support out-of-order packets then you could extend this with an IPSec ESP-style sequence number window.

Comment: With regard to your edit, you now have enough detail that you should be able to write out a formal specification to automate security verification.   Ex: Write it in Proverif to get some certainty about your security (or ask a skilled grad student or contract a company).

Answer (score 2):

in general, a widely used algorithm to exchange/set up session keys is Diffie Hellman. While exchanging public keys, during the process a shared key is generated, that could also be used to encrypt the communication, without additonal AES.

I do not know how deep your knowledge of asymmetric encryption is- generally, there are two(three) problems that are used. None of them are trivial- factorisation, discrete logarithms and elliptic curves, the latter often combined with the first two.

However, I'm missing out some details that would help- would you rather have a fast encryption (because in that case I would recommend an elliptic-curve based Diffie Hellman, as ECDH) or an easy implementation (standard DH). Is it important that the algorithm is CCA secure(DH is not). How high shall the security be- how much computation power do you have? Can the key of the IPhone change, or should it always be the same? It would also be helpful to know what kind of bluetooth device it is.

Another approach would be using one-time keys. The communication could be initiated by the bluetooth device, which has a storage of several keys that may only be used once- in this case to encrypt the session key.

Last but not least, CTR mode is considered less secure than other cipher modes of AES. Personally, I would recommend GCM for you- because I like it, and because it also provides authenticated encryption, and can be pipelined easily. It has a 128 bit block size. If you expect many errors, OFB could be useful for you... but that goes too far. If you clarify your question a bit more as I‘ve indicated, I can help you out further.

Comment: The target bluetooth device is an embedded device with very limited resources and processing power. Another thing I should mention is that we can't guarantee that all packets will get through, any packet could potentially get lost and never show up at the intended destination. Packets are limited to 20 bytes, on top of which we have our own communication protocol implemented. On the iPhone side, we have a lot of CPU power, but that doesn't help the embedded side. So we will probably need fast encryption. I just need to keep potential hackers from controlling our devices.

Comment: Okay. On which layer is the protocol implemented (this is something really, really crucial!)? 
You will not get fast and secure encryption with limited ressources. From my very limited experience with embedded devices, the key size in asymmetric encryption can impose a problem. Could you give any numbers?

Comment: Our custom protocol is just being run on top of the normal bluetooth services and characteristics. Current approach is one characteristic is a command characteristic for sending commands. Another is a response characteristic that the device uses to send responses back to the phone. It is this custom command/response protocol that I want to encrypt to keep people from sniffing important connection information.

Comment: For reference, here are the specifications for the bluetooth chip we are going to be using. https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF52832

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you use a widely accepted key-exchange technique, such as STS. I linked to my own STS specification and implementation in the comments if you are curious it might be educational.

Much of this is vague.  "Start of any connection"  is not specific enough for me, for example.  A communication diagram would help here.

That said, here are some thoughts

> 1. Communication is between an iPhone and a bluetooth peripheral. At the start of any connection, the iPhone will generate a random public/private key pair. The public key will be sent to the bluetooth device.

And the device can safely trust this is the correct public key?

> The bluetooth device will generate a random symmetric key, encrypt it using the iPhone's public key and send it back to the iPhone.

My current understanding is the following could happen:

```
Device        |    Adversary       |    Computer
E_p1(randKey) ----> E_p2(randKey2) --->
```

Where `p1` is the adversary's public key and `p2` is the computer's (or iphone's) public key.

So now the device is actually talking to the adversary in the middle, right?

> All future communication will now be performed using the symmetric key for encryption/decryption.

The device uses `randKey` to talk to the adversary and the computer users `randKey2`.

> A security passkey that is generated once for the bluetooth device and used to identify an authorized user is encrypted and sent from the iOS device to the bluetooth device. If the passkey is wrong, the connection is killed.

It would be wise to use a challenge-response and not a plaintext password.  As I see it, the adversary now has the password (and can forward it on to the device so there is no loss of functionality visible to the user).

> If it is correct, the iOS device now has full access to the bluetooth device via encrypted packet communication. Each new connection will have a new private/public key pair and a new symmetric key.

Now that you've outlined the key exchange you should also think thought this "encrypted packet communication" since that can be non-trivial as well.  Is replay OK?  Are out-of-order messages OK?  How are you ensuring IVs are not reused?  Does the key ever "die"?

A more paranoid question: Do you trust the RNG on the bluetooth device? Why? If it is responsible for all the entropy in the key then it better be great.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I see that there are a lot of holes in my thinking and what I was planning on doing. I've outlined above what I hope is a better approach that doesn't involve exchanging keys. If you could give me your opinion I'd really appreciate it.