# GCM mode of operation with long-term keys

Tags: authenticated-encryption, gcm, xor

Regarding GCM, NIST [specifies](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf#page=29) the following:

> The total number of invocations of the authenticated encryption function **shall not exceed $2^{32}$**, including all IV lengths and all instances of the authenticated encryption function with the given key.

In [another thread on this forum](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52925/77), @Lery suggests deriving session keys from the long-term key using a [key-derivation function (KDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) by computing $k_s = \mathrm{KDF}(k,r)$. Here, $k$ is the long-term key, and $r$ is a random nonce generated per GCM usage. $k_s$ is the key used for GCM.

This makes sense from a security standpoint, but to increase performance, I'd like to investigate whether computing the session key as $k_s = k \oplus r$ poses any threat to the security of GCM.

You can assume that the value of $r$ is appended to the ciphertext, but is not encrypted. So, anyone seeing the ciphertext can easily deduce the value of $r$.

The adversary is said to attack this scheme if he can break the properties often associated with authenticated encrypted: **IND-CCA security**, or **unforgeability**.

Comment: Key derivation functions are pretty fast. You can even generate a KDF by using a single run of a hash function over the master key and a counter. Besides that, even $2^{24}\cdot16=268435456$, about 268 MB. On KBKDF per 268 MB will not slow down computation much. Note that you can use a KBKDF rather than a PBKDF (also known as a password hash). KBKDF's can be pretty fast.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I've also considered your points, but unfortunately they are moot in the application I'm working on. Besides, the question is interesting from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: No problem, it is not an answer. But as others may read the same Q/A it is important to note these things somewhere... already voted the question up.

Comment: Can you expand on what engineering constraints lead you to conclude that Maarten's suggestions are moot for your application?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: A very tiny piece of hardware with extremely low amount of resources.

Comment: What is your specific budget, and hardware capabilities, such that (a) you can compute AES-GCM on gigabytes of data, but (b) you can't compute HKDF-SHA256 once to derive a subkey?  If the issue is SHA-256 _vs._ AES, you could use $k_n = \operatorname{AES}_k(n \mathbin\| 0) \mathbin\| \operatorname{AES}_k(n \mathbin\| 1)$ where $n$ is the nonce to derive a single-use subkey $k_n$ for the $n^{\mathit{th}}$ message (or just $\operatorname{AES}_k(n)$ if you're using AES-128, but you should use AES-256 unless you can argue that it's beyond your budget and ${\lll}$128-bit security is enough).

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: Ridiculous as it may sound, that's the painful reality. An example would be a hardware on battery which is supposed to work 5 years or longer. With AES-GCM for authenticated encryption of messages, it may just pass this stringent requirement with a close call, but any extra operation cannot be tolerated.

Comment: Can you derive a fresh subkey once every, say, gigabyte of data?  Surely the cost of (a) a counter, and (b) one or two extra AES invocations for every gigabyte of data can't substantively affect your budget?  Presumably you already have the counter for nonces anyway.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: I oversimplified the case. The keys are encrypted with a master key, and every key usage requires the keys being decrypted first in a security core which has many other restrictions. Believe me, my special case is very special ;)

Comment: OK.  It might help if you could specify in a question exactly what your capabilities and constraints are, since it is definitely not a good idea to try to do subkey derivation by xor.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: Sure XOR is bad. I just wanted to see if there's a real attack in this particular case, which is seemingly so (as your answer indicates). I need to further understand the answer before deciding on what to do next.

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to AES-GCM: AES and GHASH.  This can completely ruin the security of both of them.  AES is [not designed to resist related-key attacks](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/317), so you're in hot water already if you derive multiple keys like this.  Not only does GHASH not resist related-key attacks, but it has a particularly simple structure that illustrates how bad things can get if you make this mistake.

GHASH authenticates a series of messages $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_\ell$ with a long-term key $k$ and a per-message key $s_i$ by $m_i \mapsto \operatorname{GHASH}_k(m_i) + s_i$.  Note that xor, $\oplus$, is just addition in the field $\operatorname{GF}(2^{128})$ that GHASH works in, and for a single-block message, $\operatorname{GHASH}_k(m_i) = m_i \cdot k$ is just multiplication, so the authenticator is simply $m_i \cdot k + s$.

Suppose the sender authenticates a (say) one-block message $m_0$ under $k$ with $r_0$ and a one-block message $m_1$ under $k$ with $r_1$.  That is, suppose you use $k \oplus r_0$ instead of $k$ for one purpose and $k \oplus r_1$ instead of $k$ in another purpose.  Then the adversary learns the authenticators $a_0 = m_0 \cdot (k + r_0) + s$ and $a_1 = m_1 \cdot (k + r_1) + s$.  By the advanced cryptanalytic technique of subtraction, the adversary will find $$a_0 - a_1 = (m_0 - m_1) k + m_0 r_0 - m_1 r_1$$ which they can easily solve for $k$ and forge messages under *any* nonce $r_i$ of their choice with wild abandon.